# How Can I Display Images When Clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a card matching game. I watched a Youtube Tutorial about it. But the cards does not show up even if I write the exact code from the video. The aim is matching two same characters. The characters should show up when a portal is clicked. So what's the problem here? Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

    const cardArray = [
        {   
            name: 'beth',
            img: 'images/beth.png'
        },  

        {   
            name: 'beth',
            img: 'images/beth.png'
        }, 

        {   
            name: 'jerry',
            img: 'images/jerry.png'
        },    

        {   
            name: 'jerry',
            img: 'images/jerry.png'
        }, 

        {   
            name: 'morty',
            img: 'images/morty.png'
        },    

        {   
            name: 'morty',
            img: 'images/morty.png'
        }, 

        {   
            name: 'mrpoopybutthole',
            img: 'images/mrpoopybutthole.png'
        }, 
    
        {   
            name: 'mrpoopybutthole',
            img: 'images/mrpoopybutthole.png'
        },  

        {   
            name: 'rick',
            img: 'images/rick.png'
        },    

        {   
            name: 'rick',
            img: 'images/rick.png'
        },

        {   
            name: 'summer',
            img: 'images/summer.png'
        }, 
        
        {   
            name: 'summer',
            img: 'images/summer.png'
        }  
    ]


cardArray.sort(()=> 0.5 - Math.random());

const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
const resultDisplay = document.querySelector('#result');
var cardsChosen = [];
var cardChosenId = [];
var cardsWon = [];


function createBoard() {
    for(let i=0; i<cardArray.length; i++){
        var card = document.createElement('img');
        card.setAttribute('src','images/portal.png');
        card.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        card.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
        grid.appendChild(card);
    }
}

function checkForMatch(){
    var cards = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    const optionOneId = cardsChosenId[0];
    const optionTwoId = cardsChosenId[1];

    if (cardsChosen[0] === cardsChosen[1]) {
        alert('You found a match');
        cards[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/white.png');
        cards[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/white.png');
        cardsWon.push(cardsChosen);
    }

   else {
       cards[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/portal.png');
       cards[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'image/portal.png');
       alert('Sorry, try again');
   } 

   cardsChosen = [];
   cardChosenId= [];
   resultDisplay.textContent = cardsWon.length;

   if (cardsWon.length === cardArray.length/2){
        resultDisplay.textContent = 'Congratulations! You found them all!';
   }

}


function flipCard(){
    var cardId= this.getAttribute('data-id');
    cardsChosen.push(cardArray[cardId].name);
    cardsChosenId.push(cardId);
    this.setAttribute('src',cardArray[cardId].img);

    if(cardsChosen.length === 2){
        setTimeout(checkForMatch,500);
    }


}
createBoard();

});
```

Comment: Could you please also show a video from youtube?

Comment: To identify where your code is not behaving as you expect: set debugger breakpoints (or console log) at different points through your code, this will let you know which lines specifically didn't behave as you expected, e.g. does `flipCard` actually invoke, what is `this` in `flipCard`, etc - then you'll either be able to make a minimal example for asking here, or you'll see and be able to fix the bug immediately

Comment: You are using `cardsChosenId` in `flipCard`, but only `cardChosenId` is defined outside it.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I realized I also made the same mistake in different parts of the code. Now it's works okay.